# What does cache mean?

Tags: software-engineering

I'm kinda new to the programming scene. I'm still a high school student but I want to be a game designer so I'm studying independently before I graduate to get an edge. The issue with this is that although I have learned some programming, I can't follow all of the technical terms that get thrown around on the game dev forums. One of the terms that gets used a lot is cache, and I'm wondering what that means. Outside of programming it means a secret stash of something you don't want others to know about, which could be referring to things like AI, login info or, something like that. I would like a more specific answer if anyone would be willing to give the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generically in software, "Caching" means keeping a local copy of some data that either:

- Is stored elsewhere in a harder-to-reach place (like on the hard drive rather than in RAM, or hosted on a server somewhere on the web)

or

- Is time-consuming to compute from scratch

This way we can save the time of re-fetching/re-computing the data when we need it repeatedly.

.

One common place this comes up is the **CPU cache**. It turns out that accessing data in memory, though much faster than reading from the hard drive, is still painfully slow in CPU terms. To hide this delay, your processor has a tiny amount of extremely fast memory built into the chip. This is the CPU cache. Whenever your game wants to access data from main memory, the chip first checks if it the data is in the cache. If not, then it requests it from main RAM, and then stores the result in the cache so that the next time it looks for that data, it will be lightning fast.

If you access the same data a lot, the average cost of each access goes down, since you're only paying the big time hit on the first attempt to access it from RAM. That makes it seem like the memory is keeping up with the CPU better than the hardware really is. ;)

Of course, the CPU cache is limited in size, so if you're accessing data from all over memory, eventually old data will be flushed out to make room for something else. This leads to the principle of **data locality**: your program runs fastest if you do a lot of work with clusters of adjacent memory (so most of your accesses are served by the cache), rather than jumping all over the place (which "thrashes" the cache by continuously flushing & re-requesting data, so it's not as effective at hiding memory latency)

[Game Programming Patterns has a great write-up on CPU caching and data locality](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html) if you'd like more information. It's a huge field and I've only described a shallow version of it above.

.

Another common place you'll see caching is in **web development**. Your browser typically doesn't re-download a website from scratch on every visit. Instead, it keeps a cache of "temporary internet files" on your hard drive, and only re-downloads files which might have changed (according to the caching information provided when they were last downloaded). This saves on bandwidth and makes loading faster.

In turn, the server you're requesting the files from is probably caching them too, so it doesn't have to look them up from disc (or another server) if the same file is requested by multiple users.

.

In game development, an engine that streams assets like textures on demand might maintain a cache of recently-used textures, on the hunch that they might be needed again soon. For instance, as you walk away from a village, the engine removes the objects inside the buildings, knowing they won't be visible. But it's likely to keep (the small mips of) their textures in its asset cache, so that if you turn around and run back to the village, it can display them again quickly without needing to load the textures off the hard drive (or worse, off of the game disc).

A game script that does target selection might keep a cache of recent target candidates that it uses for its most frequent updates, and only query for a new set of candidates every n frames, to reduce how often it performs what might be an expensive search through all the possible targets in the scene.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a great way of explaining it. I have seen this sort of thing before, but I had no idea that's what it was called.